# Attaining extrema when a stationarity condition has no solution

Tags: variational-principle, variational-calculus, optimization

I was wondering if someone could shed some light on the following for me:

If a stationarity (maximizing or minimizing) condition has no solution inside a particular domain, then how do we reason that the extrema must be attained on the boundary of the domain? Is there a proof for this anywhere?

Comment: Would [math.se] be a better home for this question?

Comment: I just realized I posted this on physics, rather than mathematics stack exchange. Apologies!

Answer (score 0):

The argument requires the assumption that $f$ is real and continuous.

If so, use the [extreme value theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Extreme_value_theorem) which states that if $f : X \to R$ is continuous for some compact set $X$, then there exists an $x \in X$ such that $f(x) \geq f(y)$ for all $y \in X$.

By assumption, there are no extremal points in the interior of $X$. So they must occur on the boundary.